# node.js node-red - Converto Base64 string to uint8array

Tags: node.js, buffer, node-red, uint8array, tobase64string

I am using Node Red to implement a web service and I am racking my brains to convert a base64 string to byte array (uint8array) or convert buffer to uint8array.

One "node" of my node-red flow outputs an image as a buffer or a base64 string.
I need to pass the responsed image into a web service which requires an uint8array base image.

There is a lot of answers using atob and btoa but node red does not support it.

Below is the output buffer format that I need to convert
[image]

And this is the buffer format what I want:

[image]

Here is the documentation of the web service I want to call:

https://demous-cdb.thereforeonline.com/theservice/v0001/restun/help/operations/CreateDocument

[image]

## [image]

I have tryed a lot of ways:

```
function toArrayBuffer(myBuf) {
   var myBuffer = new ArrayBuffer(myBuf.length);
   var res = new Uint8Array(myBuffer);
   for (var i = 0; i < myBuf.length; ++i) {
      res[i] = myBuf[i];
   }
   return myBuffer;
}
```

=====

Also tryed to use...

```
var buf = Buffer.from(b64string, 'base64')
```

The solution above does not generates an uint8array

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

The base64 node (https://flows.nodered.org/node/node-red-node-base64) should convert the base64 to buffer which you can then use as input to what ever node you are using to send to the webservice.

The NodeJS Buffer is a subclass of Uint8Array, they are just ways to represent collections of bytes.

Comment: Hi hardillib, thanks for your prompt response... The base64 node do exactly the command `Buffer.from(b64string, 'base64')`. The output is a buffer type the attached print screen 1, but I need an array buffer as show the print screen 2.

Comment: Can you edit the question to include a link to the actual doc for the webservice you are trying to call.

Comment: @hardillib Edited... I am referring to the buffer of **node-red-contrib-image-tools** node [link](https://flows.nodered.org/node/node-red-contrib-image-tools). As image attached. Do you have any idea? Many thanks for your help